# Porting Music Player Daemon (MPD) to Android

Tags: android, c++, c

I am looking to port MPD, the music player daemon (SERVER, I note there are plenty of clients) to the Android platform. I was wondering if anyone had any advice to this end?

So far I imagine it will involve getting the sources of MPD (can't do that at work so will check tonight), finding an Android compiler and building all the dependencies and MPD itself using that? I believe the Android NDK can compile C and C++ into .apk's which then run in an Android virtual machine, but I'm not sure what issues that might cause on MPD in terms of accessing the audio hardware etc..

Failing this, perhaps an alternative is to install Linux for Android and run MPD directly out of that? I want to stick my phone straight into a speaker and use it to play music from a Windows or Linux machine on my LAN - this is exactly what MPD enables so I would really like to see a server port for Android, as would many others from what I've seen in my searching for it.

Comment: XBMC for Android is now available, which enables this kind of thing, if you couple it with VNC or something to control the device remotely and change songs/playlist.

Answer (score 0):

MPD Android port is now available as a separate app, it is free and open-source:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=be.deadba.ampd

http://tguillem.github.io/android-ampd/

Gravedigging yay.